# MongoDB - How to access nested array and object then $sum

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a document with an array that contains a list of objects, and each object has an array. I need to get the total points per team that are stored in the inner array (points).

It should return an output of:

- **8** total points for Team  1
- **10** total points for Team 2
- **12** total points for Team 3

This is the document.

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "0123456789"
  },
  "teams": [
    {
      "team": "Team 1",
      "captain": "Ryan",
      "points": [2, 2, 2, 2]
    },
    {
      "team": "Team 2",
      "captain": "Josh",
      "points": [2, 2, 3, 3]
    },
    {
      "team": "Team 3",
      "captain": "Amiel",
      "points": [3, 3, 3, 3]
    }]
}]
```

I have something along this line but it is incorrect.

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: "0123456789"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      points: {
        $sum: "$teams.points"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you are trying to add a new field: `totalPoints` to each document in the `teams` array.

1. `$set` - Set `teams` array field.

   1.1. `$map` - Iterate each element in the `teams` array and return a new array.

   1.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge current iterated document in the `teams` array with the result of *1.1.1.1*.

   1.1.1.1. A document with `totalPoints` field with the value of the total sum of `points` array.

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: "0123456789"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      teams: {
        $map: {
          input: "$teams",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                totalPoints: {
                  $sum: "$$this.points"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yu9-HRFZ62b)

Comment: Hello. This is nice. What's the approach if I simply want to get the total points of a specific team? Like I just want a single output that is "8" for team 1.

Comment: Unsure what is your expected output for the document. Perhaps this is something you want? [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z61FyG5pOBS)